# Uppercasing all strings of certain column using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I am using QGIS.

I have two shapefiles which I want to join based on address columns. SO far I have not been able to join them. I think the reason might be that one column is capitalized while the other one is NOT all capitalized.

Below are screenshots of the two columns:

[image: anderson_parcel add column]

[image: customer_billing address column]

How can I capitalize all the strings of "address_2" columns?

Comment: Did you look in the strings menu, look for to_upper or upper

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you will first join the shapefiles together and then use the "Field Calculator" to create a new column that combines the two address columns together.

Comment: @Zman3 Do you know if it is possible to join the shapefiles without specifying join fields?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I am following you, but I would suggest having a similar `id` column in both shapefiles and joining based on that. Would it be possible to share your shapefiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not case sensitive.

**Step 1**

I have two shapefiles. Circles and Squares. Both have an `id` column/field and both have an `address` column/field.
[image]

**Step 2**

Use the `Join Attributes by Field Values` tool. For the "Layer 2 fields to copy", select the other shapefiles address column. You can choose to "discard the records which could not be joined" as well. You're call. Save and Run.
[image]

**Step 3**

Open the attribute table of the newly created layer and see that they joined based on the `id` field.
[image]

**step 4**

Create a new field and make sure the "Output length" is set high enough for all characters to be present from the concatenation of addresses. Then perform the operation you want. Here I combined the address separated by an `--`.
[image]

**Step 5**

Final Results
[image]

**EDITS**

You are correct in thinking that the text needs to match (case sensitive).

1. Update your address field to all CAPS. Reference @hugonbg answer.
2. Perform the same steps indicated below expect use the address field as your "Table field" parameter indicated in "Step 2".

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't share any columns (including id fields) except for the address columns, which I provided their screenshots at top

Comment: @KavehEkbia So how do you know which row from shapefile 1 joins with shapefile 2?

Comment: There are multiple rows from customer_billing(shapefile1) and AndersonParcel2021 (shapefile2) that share a same address. As an example there is a row from shapefile1 that has “2879 E CREEKS DR” and there is a row from shapefile2 that has this value “2879 E Creeks DR”. Therefore these two rows join. There are many other rows similar to the example I just provided. The only difference is that shapefile1 address values are all uppercase while shapefile2 address values are not all uppercase.

Comment: Do you know how I can make it to work?

Comment: @KavehEkbia please see the `EDITS` section and let me know if that works!

Comment: It worked perfectly.

Comment: That's great! If you could either mark mine or @hugonbg answer correct that would be great!

Comment: Certainly. I wish I could mark both since you both provided great help. Yours is marked. :)

Answer (score 8):

Using QGIS, you can use the upper("column name") expression.
Open the layer attributes table with the lowercase text, then the field calculator (CTRL+i) and type upper("column name") in the expressions field.
Also check 'update existing column' and select the column with the address, you can create a new column too if you prefer.

[image]